# robot framework python unable to open browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am new to robot framework python, I am using eclipse RED editor.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

MyFirstTest

    Log    Hello World...

    
FirstSeleniumTest

    Create Webdriver    chrome    executable_path=/Users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver
    Open Browser    https:google.com    chrome
    Close browser
```

I am seeing following error msg:

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am using mac. how to fix it? "Chomedriver" file exist in the Downloads path mentioned above.

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the driver_name from **c**hrome to **C**hrome. (Only with **Open
Browser** Keyword, the browser_names are case-insensitive). Make note- **Create webdriver** keyword is mostly followed by **Go to**, since you have already created your driver instance.

Comment: Thanks.

    Create webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=/Users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    Chrome
    Close Browser

 Chrome browser opens now but it doesn't close. I get following error msg.

 WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

 path specified is correct. Not sure what's missing. please help.

Comment: The keyword 'Open Browser' triggers an error if you dont have the chromerdriver executable in PATH. Setting Custom executable path can be done only with 'Create Webdriver' Keyword. So if you want to use 'Open Browser' Keyword, add the chromedriver location into your PATH environment variable.

Comment: '*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
FirstSeleniumTest-1
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=/Users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver
    Go To  https:google.com
    Close browser
FirstSeleniumTest-2
    Open browser    https:google.com        chrome
    Close browser'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what aravinth_2442 has said, you also have a wrong URL as an argument to `Open Browser` keyword. It might be just a typo here in your question, but you should correct it as well to:

```
Open Browser    https://www.google.com    Chrome
```

You can see the official documentation here: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser So make sure, you type correctly the names of browsers, they are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks.

    Create webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=/Users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    Chrome
    Close Browser

 Chrome browser opens now but it doesn't close. I get following error msg.

 WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

 path specified is correct. Not sure what's missing. please help.

Comment: You either need to specify `executable_path` with the keyword, which in your example seems to be defined incorrectly. By the names, it seems you're on Windows, but path `/Users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver` is incorrect, there's for instance no drive letter specified. Fix this. Or you can change the value of `PATH` variable and leave out `executable_path` from the list of arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks.

I am on mac, not windows. could advise what do you mean by executable_path with the keyword?

FirstSeleniumTest
    Create webdriver    chrome    executable_path=/users/ljames/Downloads/chromedriver
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    chrome
    Close Browser

 chrome doesn't open with www.google.com, it opens with "data:,". What am I missing here? @aravinth_2442

Comment: Ok, you got the path working. "could advise what do you mean by executable_path with the keyword?" Just read what you're posting, it's right there in your example. And in the documentation that you should be reading. You can find it here: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html search for your keywords and follow the text, you should be able to fix it faster than waiting here for answers.